# Google Analytics track referrals with query strings

Tags: google-analytics

How does one track referrals with query strings? I found articles describing filters but they're all from 2011 and the current dashboard doesn't match what I see in the articles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interface has changed quite a bit since then. However, the same filters would continue to work. You'd need to go to Admin > All filters to create the filter.

Comment: for who doesn't know in the new interface the filter will be in Audience-> Custom -> User defined